# 256 byte long RSA encryption of AES key

Tags: objective-c, encryption, cryptography, rsa, padding

I am trying to RSA encrypt the AES key of 32 chars length.
Finally managed to do so with the help of the pre-generated public key and this RSA implementation for objective-C:
https://github.com/ideawu/Objective-C-RSA/blob/master/RSA.m

```
NSData *enc = [RSA encryptData:data publicKey:pubkey];
```

Which then calls the library's methods. Basically, what it does is the following: it creates a SecKeyRef from public key, then it calculates the block_size, data_size etc. And finally it calls the

```
SecKeyEncrypt(keyRef, kSecPaddingPKCS1, srcbuf + idx, data_len, outbuf, &outlen);
```

I don't really understand what is going inside the encryption methods, but the outcome is the correctly created encrypted key.

Then I am able to decrypt it with a public key with the help of

```
SecKeyDecrypt(keyRef, kSecPaddingNone, srcbuf + idx, data_len, outbuf, &outlen);
```

The result is absolutely correct.

But the encoded key is 144 bytes long. It is not what I need. For some reason I need the key to be exactly 256 bytes.

My first thought was to fill the rest bytes with some constant variable (e.g. 0), but I thought it is not how it should be done.

The next thought was to use different padding. The name kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA256 sounded like the correct padding, but encoding the key with it instead of the kSecPaddingPKCS1 caused the app to fail with the error:

```
SecKeyEncrypt fail. Error Code: -50
```

I suppose it has something to do with the block_size, but I have little understanding of the insides of the encryption.

I need the encoded key to be exactly 256 bytes long, how can I do that?

Comment: When you state: "But the encoded key is 144 bytes long. It is not what I need. For some reason I need the key to be exactly 256 bytes.", what needs to be 256 bytes?

Comment: the RSA-ecrypted key (that was 32 chars long before encryption) should be appended to the beginning of a message int the first 256 bytes. When I encode it, I get only 144. Don't know how to fill the rest. Thought padding was for it, but failed to implement it.

Comment: Do you mean to encrypt with `kSecPaddingPKCS1` and decrypt with `kSecPaddingNone`, that does not seem to be correct.

Comment: actually, it is how it was in the realization from the link above. I wondered why it worked too. Tried to change both to kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA256, still the error.

Comment: @zaph I tried it with both being kSecPaddingPKCS1 - it works the same - 144 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encrypt your data with an RSA key of 2048 bits (i.e. 256 bytes). In that case the modulus will be 256 bytes and the resulting ciphertext - in this case the wrapped key - will be of that size as well.

What you do *not* need to do is to prefix the decrypted AES key to the ciphertext - that doesn't make sense. What you need to do is to prefix the *encrypted* or *wrapped* AES key using *the public key of the receiver*.

After decryption the resulting AES key should be 256 bits (i.e. 32 bytes) again.

---

As for the padding, the padding should always be identical during encryption and decryption. Currently only [OAEP](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/secpadding/1617929-oaep) padding is considered secure. If you use PKCS#1 padding you must make sure that you're not vulnerable against padding oracle attacks.

For the same reason it is recommended to use AES-GCM instead of CBC, CBC is *also* vulnerable against padding oracle attacks.

1024 bit RSA is usually not considered secure anymore. Use a key of 2048 at the very minimum.

Comment: It is strange, because the task clearly tells me to use RSA 1024. I will try the 2048 one then.
I see the point with prefixing the message with the receiver's public key encrypted AES-key. Actually, it was what I am trying to do (maybe I was incorrect while questioning).

Comment: I tried the 2048 key with the same methods and it failed. Does not encrypt and decrypt anymore. Can't find what else is needed to be changed. The only outputs I manage to get are the 144 bytes, if the 32-byte key is encrypted with RSA 1024 public key, or 0 bytes when something in the RSA realisation methods fails.

Comment: I've found out that I've been wrong all the time - the actual size of the encrypted key is 128. It was my mistake with the size determination.
Still not 256 though...

Comment: I suppose there might be something wrong with the files from that link. The encryption only started working after I commented the line that was stripping the private key - there was something about the magic 22nd byte.

Comment: I don't particularly like *wrapper classes* like the one you pointed out. Often it is easier to use directly the crypto API's available from libraries or the platform. In this case it skips the unpadding, which means it is **completely insecure**. Don't trust random crypto code.

Comment: Firstly i tried to do it the way you've said, but as I don't understand the cryptography well, I decided to search for the ways it should be done. Spent the whole day searching for the Objective-C solution and that was the only one I was able to make working.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/bigsan/RSAESCryptor/blob/master/RSAESCryptor/RSAESCryptor.m) should be a better example, which does use RSA. Don't use it for transport security though. You can strip the certificate and IV related code from it. Beware of the literals used within the code though, use (predefined) constants whereever you can.

Comment: Wow! All this time I've been doing the things that are already implemented (not a news, but still wasn't able to find it). And there are event the AES and RSA together, which I was connecting manually. Thank you! I will have a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: It turned out to be a mistake in the task - 128 bytes should be prefixed to the message, not the 256 bytes.

Comment: I read that RSA 1024 is weak and should not be used, but for the unknown reasons the task says to still use RSA 1024.
Thank you for help!